# Подскажите сайт с хешами md5

Tags: md5

Подскажите сайт с хешами md5 на подобии [такого](http://www.cmd5.org/).

Comment: а этот чем не устраивает?

Comment: не нашел нужного хеша

Comment: Ищите по ключевой фразе "rainbow tables"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно зачем топикстартёру хЭши (не хЕши) MD5, но коли уж вопрос задан - направлю к широко известному в узких кругах сайту [Форуму АНТИЧАТ](http://forum.antichat.ru/) там собирается тусовка любителей поломать хэши на спор - естественно там же выкладываются различные хэши (не только MD5) - есть ссылки на софт, на разные сайты по схожей теме.

Answer (score 1):

То что вы ищете называется Радужными таблицами, в данном случае для md5.
[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

[Ссылки](http://project-rainbowcrack.com/table.htm) для скачивания.

В гугле ключевые слова: rainbow tables md5